# Find a projective variety $Z$ and closed subsets $X,Y \subseteq Z$ with $\dim(X)+\dim(Y) \geq \dim(Z)$ and $X \cap Y = \varnothing$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am trying to find a projective variety $Z$ and closed subsets $X,Y \subseteq Z$ with $\dim(X)+\dim(Y) \geq \dim(Z)$ and $X \cap Y = \varnothing$.

However, all my attempts failed.

In fact, we cannot have $Z=\mathbb{P}^n$ for any $n$. If we had that, and knowing that $dim(\mathbb{P}^n)=n$, we had $\dim(X)+\dim(Y) \geq n$ and then $X \cap Y$ is non-empty (it's a result that I proved previously).

So, I tried things like the union of the graph of two parabolas that are disjoint, but this kind of things have always a common point in $\mathbb{P}^2$

Also, if $X,Y$ are points, such as $X=\{(1:0:0)\}$ and $Y=\{(0:1:0)\}$, we have $\dim(X)=\dim(Y)=0$.
If we take $Z=X \cup Y$, does it work?

I'm a bit lost... maybe a hint will lead me to a correct example.

Thanks!

Edit: Of course it doesn't work. I found that $V(z^2-yz-y^2+x^2+2xy)$ is irreducible, and then is a projective variety of dimension $1$. Now I am trying to find some $X$ closed of dimension $1$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the direct product of two projective lines or, better, of a projective line and projective n-space for any n.

Comment: First, let me thank you for answering to my question. I tried $X=\{(1:a:0):a \in \mathbb{K}\}$, $X=\{(0:1:b):b \in \mathbb{K}\}$ and $Z:=X \times Y$. The dimensions and the intersection it's easy to check. The inclusions $X,Y \subseteq Z$ and the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are closed in $Z$ are not really a problem, but are we able to find a suitable $Z$ with a ''real'' inclusion, ie, here $X,Y \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2$ and $Z \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2$. Thanks again

Comment: Google for "Segre embedding".

Comment: Ok, then $Z = \sigma(X \times Y) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^8$ is a projective variety, where $\sigma$ is Segre embedding. How do I look $X,Y \subseteq \sigma(X \times Y)$?

Comment: Pick a point $x\in X$ and consider the subset $\{x\}\times Y$, and similar with the other one.

Comment: So, you pick $X',Y'$ two lines (for example, those that I mentioned before) and set $X=\sigma(X' \times \{y\}), Y=\sigma(\{x\} \times Y')$, where $x \in X'$ and $y \in Y'$ are fixed. Then, we set $Z=\sigma(X' \times Y')$. Is this that you're saying? (Sorry to bother you with this...)

Comment: No, that is not hat I am saying: the sets X and Y you mention **do** intersect, as you could have seen immediately! Take points $x$, $x'\in X$ and consider he subsets $A=\{x\}\times Y$ and $B=\{x'\}\times Y$ inside $Z=X\times Y$. My $A$ and $B$ are obviously disjoint. Now take $A$, $B$ and $Z$ and apply $\sigma$.

Comment: For an easy concrete example, just look at a smooth quadric surface, {\em e.g.} $V(xy-zw) \subseteq \mathbb P^3$ and the lines $L_1=V(x-z, y-w)$ and $L_2=V(x-2z, y-\frac{1}{2}w)$.